# Retrieve image in HTML from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, image

I have a PHP file running on the server that gets a jpeg image from the server using
`echo file_get_contents().`

I want to retrieve this image using Ajax and display in an HTML file on the client side. I receive the contents properly but I am not being able to display the image properly.

I ve tried this to display the image but it does not get set:

```
document.getElementById("profilePic").src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+msg;
document.getElementById("profilePic").src=msg;
```

If I use

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=msg;
```

I can see the image in text format.(ie if I open the image using notepad).

Can not figure out where I am going out wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If you have set the header of your php file as an image, you should be able to simply do : document.getElementById("profilePic").src = "path/to/your/imageFile.php";

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set the header before using echo?
From: http://www.ehow.com/how_7280601_send-php-image-file.html

`$img_data = file_get_contents("images/phpimage.png");
 header("Content-type: image/png");
 echo $img_data;`

Comment: I am pretty sure I am getting the image to the Client(HTML), I am not being able to display it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you want

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
var z = document.getElementById("img1");
    x.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+msg);
  x.setAttribute("class", "imgstyle");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "test");
```

Comment: Do I need to write z=x or something after this(did not work)

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("profilePic");
    x.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+msg);`  try this 
it works on my side

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not try to parse it in html, but let the browser do the processing, you just map it to `src` attrib, like this:

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/dGOMzW?editors=101

```
    var picurl = "https://lh3.ggpht.com/lF8X5d9R-agU1_vrapxP8r8gxZjP21awryU_FLExYvvnReGMOp39tRxI4gSY9yqNyuRO=w300";
    $.ajax({
        url: picurl,
        success: function(data){
            var pic = $('<img>');
            pic.attr( 'src', picurl );
            pic.appendTo( 'body' );
        },
    });
```

jQuery or javascript is overkill here I think.

cheers